# How to avoid Logo changing position on resizing of window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on Bootstrap `navbar` and after resizing as the hamburger menu shows the logo shifts its position and even overflows the `navbar`. How can I make the logo responsive so that it changes its size or position as the `navbar` is resized in the window?

```
        <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar-outer">
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin:0px;">


           <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
   <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                </button>
           </div>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                     <img src="../images/LOL_LOGO_NEW-01.png" />
                </a>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu"> 
            <ul class="navbar navbar-nav" id="navbar-menu">
                <li><a href="#" >WHAT WE DO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WHO WE ARE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">OUR WORK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VENTURES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONNECT</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, along with the answer if you could provide me with the reason as to why it happened then it'll be appreciated as I am still in the learning phase.

Thanks. :)

[without resizing it looks normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7OCu.png)

[look how it overflows on resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkiWC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some background color so you can easily see the block for each container. The logo will be `red`, the navbar-header will be `yellow`, and the navbar-collapse will be `green`.

`navbar-brand` has a `float: left` so it will float to the left of the block, if you have it after `navbar-header`(which has `display:block` so it will take the whole width of the screen) block it will just floating left below, you can move it inside `navbar-header` or move it up outside of container-fluid.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  background: red;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

.navbar-header {
  background: yellow;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar-outer">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin:0px;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="../images/LOL_LOGO_NEW-01.png" />
      </a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="navbar navbar-nav" id="navbar-menu">
        <li><a href="#">WHAT WE DO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WHO WE ARE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OUR WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VENTURES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONNECT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why it happened? Like why does it have to be sibling with container-fluid?

Comment: @Derp give me a min I will explain

Comment: Sure. 
Also any suggestions as to why my hamburger dropdown is not expanding the navbar div? or should I post another question for that?

Comment: @Derp make sure your reference in the right order, bootstrap css then jquery then bootstrap.js

Comment: @Derp try those 3 link in the code snippet add before your `</body>` tag